# Where is source code for maven-artifact-manager 2.0.6

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I looked into official maven repo, looked through svn/git tags/branches all referenced repos but can't find sources for it.

Can anyone please help me (please!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on the [maven-artifact-manager website, in the Source repository section](https://maven.apache.org/ref/2.0.11/maven-artifact-manager/source-repository.html), you can find the link to the last version of the repository (2.0.11).

For each version, they follow the same naming rule, so the source code of the version 2.0.6 is available at this address:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/components/tags/maven-2.0.6/maven-artifact-manager/